# how to generate piechart using apache poi 4.0 XDDFChartData, XDDFPieChartData; in excel sheet using java, i dont want to use jfree

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, pie-chart

I need a sample code in Java, currently I am able to draw line charts after reading values from sheet, and I also want to generate pie chart.

Example code I have tried which is for `.ppt` format.

I want the same in excel for pie chart in java.

```
String[] categories = listCategories.toArray(new String[listCategories.size()]);
Double[] values = listValues.toArray(new Double[listValues.size()]);

final int numOfPoints = categories.length;
final String categoryDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 0, 0));
final String valuesDataRange = chart.formatRange(new CellRangeAddress(1, numOfPoints, 1, 1));
final XDDFDataSource<?> categoriesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories, categoryDataRange);
final XDDFNumericalDataSource<? extends Number> valuesData = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values, valuesDataRange);

XDDFPieChartData.Series firstSeries = (XDDFPieChartData.Series) pie.getSeries().get(0);
firstSeries.replaceData(categoriesData, valuesData);
firstSeries.setTitle(chartTitle, chart.setSheetTitle(chartTitle, 0));
firstSeries.setExplosion(25);
chart.plot(pie);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derived from the chart examples in https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/usermodel/ here is a `PieChart` example using the `XDDF` stuff:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class PieChart {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("piechart");
      final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
      final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

      // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
          cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
          if (rowIndex == 0) cell.setCellValue("Cat " + (colIndex + 1));
          else cell.setCellValue((colIndex + 1) * (rowIndex + 1));
        }
      }

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 25);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("Pie Chart");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

      XDDFChartData data = new XDDFPieChartData(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewPieChart());
      data.setVaryColors(true);
      data.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(data);
 
      // Write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pie-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

The above is the minimal example using only the `XDDF` stuff. Here is a more extended version which sets data labels and makes the chart visible in `LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc`. But this needs using the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` stuff.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFPieChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.DefaultIndexedColorMap;

public class PieChart {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
      XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("piechart");
      final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
      final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

      // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
      Row row;
      Cell cell;
      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
        row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
          cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
          if (rowIndex == 0) cell.setCellValue("Cat " + (colIndex + 1));
          else cell.setCellValue((colIndex + 1) * (rowIndex + 1));
        }
      }

      XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 25);

      XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
      chart.setTitleText("Pie Chart");
      chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
      XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
      legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

      XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
      XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
          new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

      XDDFChartData data = new XDDFPieChartData(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewPieChart());
      data.setVaryColors(true);
      XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
      chart.plot(data);

      // Add data labels
      if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) 
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.OUT_END);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(true);
      chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls()
        .addNewShowPercent().setVal(true);

      // Do not auto delete the title; is necessary for showing title in Calc
      if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
      chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);

      // Data point colors; is necessary for showing data points in Calc
      int pointCount = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount(); 
      for (int p = 0; p < pointCount; p++) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt().addNewIdx().setVal(p);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(p)
          .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(DefaultIndexedColorMap.getDefaultRGB(p+10));
      }
 
      // Write the output to a file
      try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pie-chart.xlsx")) {
        wb.write(fileOut);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

---

Since version `apache poi 4.1.1` creation of the `XDDFChartData data` must be changed like:

```
...
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
...
//XDDFChartData data = new XDDFPieChartData(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewPieChart());
XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
...
```

---

Since version `apache poi 5.0.0` the full jar of all of the schemas is `poi-ooxml-full.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

---

How to use the the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes?

Unfortunately there is no API documentation online available. But we need this. So we need downloading the sources of used `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` (up to Apache PPOI 4) or `poi-ooxml-full jar` (since Apache POI 5). Then we can create a API documentation using `javadoc`.

All Office Open XML files, so also `*.xlsx`, are simply ZIP archives. So one can unzip a `*.xlsx` file using a ZIP application (7-Zip can do that for example). Then we can have a look into the internals.

To find out what to do for charts in `*.xlsx` when high level classes of Apache POI lack support for something, do the folowing:

Create a `*.xlsx` having a chart using what Apache POI provides. Then unzip that `*.xlsx` and show the content of `xl/chart/chart*.xml`. Then open that `*.xlsx`  in Excel GUI and do what you want to do additionally. Then save. Then unzip that `*.xlsx` and show the content of `xl/chart/chart*.xml`. Now compare what has changed in XML. Now the need is to recreate those changes using code.

At first try to understand what `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*` classes needed. In XML the elements most are *C*omplex*T*ypes. So if you find an element `chart` in XML the correspondig class is `CTChart`. An XML elemernt `plotArea` is `CTPlotArea`. XML `pieChart` is `CTPieChart` and so on.

Knowing this and having created the API documentation using javadoc, one should be able to figure out which methods of which classes to use to create what is required.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot @Axel Richter thanks a lot :). Can u help me for adding data labels in  chart, as currently i have to add data labels manually in excel sheet.

Comment: @Rajesh Bhardwaj: See my supplement.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as this answer is what shows google, I would like to add that the options mentioned at `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.OUT_END` maps to the options available at "Format Data Labels" in excel (or see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y85DOG5FOVc). To open that, right click on the chart to show that menu option. That is useful if you want to hide some data. By default show almost everything. For example, to show only the value data:

```
          dLbls.addNewDLblPos().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STDLblPos.BEST_FIT);
          dLbls.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
          dLbls.addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
          dLbls.addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
          dLbls.addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
          dLbls.addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
          dLbls.addNewShowLeaderLines().setVal(false);
```