# How do I add custom colors to each slice in a Pie Chart?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pie-chart

I know I can set a boolean to true to add varying colors, which seems to be the only way to add different colors per slice.

As far as I can see, I can only do it on the series level...which will just set every slice to one color, which is not what I want. I want to set each slice a different color, but not the default ones given by apache poi.

Comment: The following linked answer shows how to create a pie chart using the `XDDF` stuff of `apache poi`. There also is a more extended version which also sets colors for each data point.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885970/how-to-generate-piechart-using-apache-poi-4-0-xddfchartdata-xddfpiechartdata-i/54891166#54891166

Comment: @AxelRichter helpful! but for 4.1.1 the following seems to no longer exist:  


`chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(0).addNewSpPr() `

There seems to be no methods available at all after `getDPtArray(0)`.

Comment: You need the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` as mentioned in [FAQ-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Comment: @AxelRichter Oh! Thank you for giving me this :) I appreciate all the help and the excellent example.

Comment: @AxelRichter Do you want to post below and have me to choose you as best answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create un dataset to change the color, this is an example

```
fun setColor() {
        val entries = arrayListOf<PieEntry>()
        val colors = arrayListOf<Int>()
        for (category in 4) {
         colors.add(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")

        }
     val dataSet = PieDataSet(entries, "")
        dataSet.colors = colors
      val data = PieData(dataSet)
       data.setValueTextSize(11f)
      data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)
      pieChart.data = data
       pieChart.highlightValues(null)
      pieChart.invalidate()
    }
```