# Pie Chart Apache POI (4.1.1) - How to get the number format of data labels to 0,00

Tags: java, apache-poi, pie-chart

I did some searching around the internet  (and the code inspection), but it seems I cannot find what im looking for...

**What I do:**
I´m creating a pie chart in an excel which works fine, EXCEPT that the percent values are shown with top many decimal places:

[image: Pie Chart with too many decimal places]

I played a bit around in the generated Excel and it would help if I could access the "Category" - Numbers property programmatically:
[image: How the chart should look like]

In my **code** I already tried to set the number format, which doesn´t change anything for me:

```java
public void createPieChartInSheet(Workbook wb, XSSFDrawing drawing, String chartTitle, XSSFClientAnchor anchor, LinkedList<Triple<String, XDDFDataSource<String>, XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double>>> chartSeries, LinkedList<byte[]> colorScheme) {
    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    chart.setTitleText(chartTitle);
    chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

    XDDFDataSource<String> cat = chartSeries.get(0).getMiddle();
    XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = chartSeries.get(0).getRight();

    XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
    Series series = data.addSeries(cat, val);
    series.setTitle(chartSeries.get(0).getLeft(), null);

    // Add data labels
    if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
    }
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewNumFmt().setFormatCode("0,00");

    setPieChartColors(colorScheme, chart, series);
    chart.plot(data);
}
```

Am I even searching for the right thing? Any help appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `Excel` chart get it's data label number format from the number format of the cells where the values are stored. That's called "source linked"  and is the default. So simply do formatting those cells using the number format you want.

But if you want to have the data labels a special other number format, you need add a `NumFmt` element to the `DLbls` element. You have done tis alrady. But this `NumFmt` must not be source linked then. And it must have it's  own `FormatCode`, which is always `en_US` in the `XML`. The localizing is done by the `Excel` `GUI` and not in the source `XML`. So it would must be `0.00` in your case since dot is decimal separator while comma is thousands separator in `en_US`. But if you want have it the default decimal number format having two decimal digits, it would must be `#,##0.00`.

Change your code as follows:

```
...
    // Add data labels
    if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
    }
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
    
    //chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewNumFmt().setFormatCode("0,00");
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().addNewNumFmt();
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getNumFmt().setSourceLinked(false);
    chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls().getNumFmt().setFormatCode("#,##0.00");
...
```

This works for me and leads to have data labels the number format `#.##0,00` in my German `Excel`, which is the default decimal number format having two decimal digits.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm =) And erm yes the formatting of the underlying data was my other "project" to work on ^^ I had my problems with that as well :/ (Will make another post, so the topics don´t get messed up...)

Comment: I am using getBarChartArray but my word document is getting corrupted

Comment: Can you please help me on this, I am not able to update labels in Category Chart - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728525/set-number-format-on-barchart-label-in-word-document-using-apache-poi

Answer (score 3):

It is always difficult to figure out problem related to Excel, as documentation is not clear and there are so many XML tag with meaningless name.

### One way I find useful is to compare the actual xml of working and not working excel file.

So I created a not working excel using program, and then edit using MS Excel to apply formatting to create a working excel.
Then by comparing *xl\charts\chart1.xml* after unzip the excel,
The problem is found and due to the following line
*From program*

```
<c:numFmt formatCode="0.00"/>
```

*After edit with MS Excel*

```
<c:numFmt formatCode="0.00" sourceLinked="0"/>
```

"0" is false and the default value is "1"(true).

From [the document of sourceLinked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.charts.numberingformat.sourcelinked?view=openxml-2.8.1), I guess the formatting will follow the source(cell original format) when set to true, so we need to set to false to make our formatting effective. We can do so by calling [CTNumFmt#setSourceLinked(boolean)](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/developing/ref/javadoc/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTNumFmt.html#setSourceLinked-boolean-) with false.

Following program demonstrate how to generate Pie chart with custom number format.(Base on [Axel Richter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885970/how-to-generate-piechart-using-apache-poi-4-0-xddfchartdata-xddfpiechartdata-i)), running on POI 4.1.1.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTDLbls;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTNumFmt;

public class CustomDecimalPlace {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("piechart");
            final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 2;
            final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    if (rowIndex == 0) {
                        cell.setCellValue("Cat " + (colIndex + 1));
                    } else {
                        cell.setCellValue(((double) 101) / ((double) (colIndex + 1)));
                    }
                }
            }

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 25);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            chart.setTitleText("Pie Chart");
            chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            XDDFDataSource<String> cat = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromStringCellRange(sheet,
                    new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet,
                    new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
            data.setVaryColors(true);
            data.addSeries(cat, val);
            chart.plot(data);
            if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
                chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
            }
            CTDLbls dLbls = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getPieChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDLbls();
            dLbls.addNewShowVal().setVal(true);
            dLbls.addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
            dLbls.addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
            dLbls.addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
            dLbls.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
            CTNumFmt addNewNumFmt = dLbls.addNewNumFmt();
            addNewNumFmt.setFormatCode("0.00");
            // Set false to not follow source format
            addNewNumFmt.setSourceLinked(false);
            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-pie-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise on debugging =) I didn´t know about that. 
For your example I had to change 
// XDDFPieChartData data = new XDDFPieChartData(chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewPieChart()); 
TO: XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.PIE, null, null);
And I don´t see any usage of the cellStyle you setup, so I guess it´s just working in the chart because your source doubles end up "right" in the excel anyways?

Comment: @Asamandra - Can you please help me out on this ? -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74728525/set-number-format-on-barchart-label-in-word-document-using-apache-poi